# Logical equivalence with tautology

Tags: logic

Is $(P \wedge \neg P) \Rightarrow Q$ equivalent with $Q$?

Comment: What do you think? Have you written, say, a truth table for your expression and checked?

Comment: Didn't think about that, they are definitely NOT equivalent. Thanks